# AngularJS TypeError: undefined is not a function on ng-view directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I'm trying to wire up a simple AngularJS app and I cannot get past a `undefined is not a function` error on my view directive. The weird thing is that the first view actually loads up and is rendered to the directive but I am unable to navigate to my 2nd view. The controllers definitely aren't running. I'm not sure what's going on here. Any ideas?

Angular version: 1.2.26 (same error with 1.2.20)

**Error**

[image: TypeError: Undefined is not a function]

**App Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('Home', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('Home controller hit.');
}]);

app.controller('About', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('About controller hit.');
}]);


app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'SiteAssets/views/home.html', controller: 'Home' })
    .when('/home', { templateUrl: 'SiteAssets/views/home.html', controller: 'Home' })
    .when('/about', { templateUrl: 'SiteAssets/views/about.html', controller: 'About' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Working on creating a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an error in a script within my Home View. I'm still having an issue with my second view loading up. Thanks to all who helped me on this issue.

Comment: You still need to inject the $document into you controllers. See [Doumentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) and look at the script example.

Comment: @JaredReeves You are correct but I have removed the `$document` reference from the controller since it is a separate issue.

Comment: Did you ever get a plnker up, or have you fixed the all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject $document into your controllers like this:

```
app.controller('About', ['$scope','$document', function ($scope, $document) {
  $document.title = 'About Us';
  console.log('About controller hit.');
}]);
```

It might be the $document that is throwing the error, as angular does not know what it is without the injection. However, the error for this issue would be an `Error: Unknown provider:`